# Probability of A or B or both

Tags: probability

If P(A) = 2/3 and P(B) = 1/4, what is P((A or B) or (A and B))?

I believe it to be:

P(A or B) = 11/12

P(A and B) = 2/12

Therefore 11/12 + 2/12 = 13/12. Am I correct?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ independent events?  If not, all we can say is $1/12 \leq P(A \text{ and } B) \leq 1/4$.

Comment: @EricTowers We could have $P(A\text{ and }B)=0$. The probabilities are small enough to allow $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint.

Comment: @Arthur : Yup.  (Arithmetic error on my part.  $2/3 + 1/4 = 11/12 < 1$.)

Comment: Yes, they are independent, sorry for not including that.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer cannot be correct, since it is larger than $1$.

It is not specified whether $A$ and $B$ are independent, and this would affect the result, but in most problems like this it's true so I'll assume it is for this answer.

$P((A\cup B)\cup(A\cap B))$ can be reduced by set theory to just $P(A\cup B)$. $P(A\cap B)=\frac2{12}$ is correct. $P(A\cup B)$ must then be calculated by inclusion-exclusion as $\frac23+\frac14-\frac2{12}=\frac9{12}=\frac34$.

Comment: Thank you, they are independent and this makes a lot of sense.